# Which is correct: "a html game" or "an html game"?

Tags: indefinite-article

Which is correct: "a html game" or "an html game"?

I think that "a html game" is correct, cause "a game" is definitely correct. But "a html" sounds somehow crooked.

Comment: If you pronounce it "hypertext markup language game", "a" is correct. If you pronounce it "aitch tee em el game" then "an" is correct.

Comment: I know people saying “haitch tee emm ell”, so for those “a html game” would be correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we speak this we say "aitch-tee-em-el game"  The first sound of "aitch" is a vowel, so we would say "an aitch-tee-em-el game" and spell this as "an html game".

The "a" or "an" purely follows the pronunciation. If the word is an acronym you may have to find out if it is pronounced as a word or by spelling the letters.

<sub>As an example, the disease AIDS "eidz" is caused by HIV "aitch-ai-vee" so "**an** AIDS patient" and "**an** HIV particle" are both correct. But Home Income Plans are called HIPs "hips" and so you would say **a** HIP. There is no real way to know that HIV and HIP are not treated the same.</sub>